# Meme expression synonyms / explanation

Tags: expressions, synonyms

Could someone please disambiguate / deconstruct all the nuanced meanings of the following types of expressions originating in internet meme culture. At some point it becomes obvious there's more than the literal meaning.

"Greedy gambler is greedy"

"Stupid brother is stupid"

Comment: Perhaps you could add a few cites or sightings to your question.  So far, your question is the only google hit for "Greedy gambler is greedy".

Comment: Know Your Meme entry: "[X Y is X](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/x-y-is-x-redundant-adjectives-are-redundant)". For what it's worth, I think there isn't anything deeper than the literal meaning plus the humour value of odd syntax (cf. "I can has cheeseburger?"). What nuance do you expect in "Long cat is long" as the caption on a photo of a long cat?

Comment: English is not my primary language, and that's the impression I got, so I figure if anyone had the answer, it'd be here. It sort of works as an added emphasis, I just wondered if there's more.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard this construction IRL, and every time I've heard it, it was used for emphasis. For example:

`Bad gamer is bad!`

Usually, it means that [y] is so [x] that a normal declaration (You're bad at this game) isn't enough; the construction brings added attention to just how [x] [y] really is.